# Pagination query exceeds the specified number of items

Tags: pagination

Assumption: 10 pieces of data per page.
Depending on the needs, it may happen that a piece of data on the first page is related to a piece of data on the third page, so these two items should be displayed next to each other on the first page. More than 10 items are allowed to appear. On the third page, that item The data is no longer displayed.
No idea.